# Access "a method of a class" in "a function of another python file" by passing the class as that function's parameter

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class file. Let's call it "C1.py". The sample code looks like below.

```
class C1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting = "Hello, world!"

    def M1(ans):
        if ans == 1 or ans == 2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Now, I have another python file in the same folder, which will access the class file shown above.

```
from trial import C1

def getAns(class1):
    while True:
        ans = input("Answer: ")
        if class1.M1(ans):
            return ans
            break

sample = C1()
print sample.greeting
ans = getAns(sample)
print ans
```

When I run those files, sample.greeting prints fine. Everything is fine until when the execution reaches the line "ans = getAns(C1)", which gives the error "M1() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)".

So, where in the code should I change so that I can call that method successfully?

Note here that the above code is only the abstraction of my whole program to highlight my problem. It sounds stupid with just the code above alone. So, please, please bear with that for me.

Comment: `def M1(self, ans):`. The first argument to a method is the implicit self.

Comment: Thanks, @AnttiHaapala, I did try that before I asked the question, and it didn't work throwing the same error. That's why here I am, yet it works now again. Anyway, so thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M1 is currently defined as a method of C1, as such it needs to have an additional self argument which would be the instance of the class. I.e

```
class C1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting = "Hello, world!"

    def M1(self, ans):
        if ans == 1 or ans == 2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

In other languages such as C++ or Java the presence of self (or this) is implicit, but in python it's explicit.

alternatively if you don't want or need M1 to access C1's state you could make M1 static via @staticmethod i.e.

```
class C1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting = "Hello, world!"

    @staticmethod
    def M1(ans):
        if ans == 1 or ans == 2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Thanks, @Robert Longson, I did try the first one before I asked the question, and it didn't work throwing the same error. That's why here I am, yet it works now again. Anyway, so thank you for your response. If you don't mind, would you elaborate a bit on the use of @staticmethod? I have never used that before and it would be nice if I get some explanations in plain English. Meanwhile, I will surf through other posts of stack overflow for it.